# jquery html() vs empty().append() performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have created a test case at http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-empty-append-test to compare the performance of `$.html()` with `$.empty().append()`. I wondered that `.empty().append()` is faster.

Can anyone explain this performance gap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `$.empty().append()` was running faster because, your selector was wrong,

You should have used `var $test = $("#test");` instead of `var $test = $("test");` for comparision.

See the **[DEMO Here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-empty-append-test/3).**

Comment: Bit selector is same in both cases.

Comment: But its returning an empty jquery Object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector correctly in jquery,

```
  $('#test').html('Example');
```

will be faster obviously than

```
  $.empty().append();
```

But

```
  $('test')
```

will search the DOM for an element with tag name 'TEST'.

Answer (score 0):

In this section you should use `innerHTML`. because this is native Javascript.

see the http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/27